# Why I can't get value printed?

Tags: java

I wrote the following program:

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class Triangle
{
   public static void main ( String [] args )
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in ) ; // new object named "scan"

       // Next lines scan ribs values into a,b,c parameters
       System.out.println ( "Please enter first rib value : "  ) ;
       int a = scan.nextInt () ; 
       System.out.println ( "Please enter second rib value : "  ) ;
       int b = scan.nextInt () ; 
       System.out.println ( "Please enter third rib value : "  ) ;
       int c = scan.nextInt () ; 
       if ( ! ( ( a >= 1 ) && ( b>=1 ) && ( c>=1 ) ) ) 
            System.out.println ( "One or more of the ribs value is negative !!\nPlease enter a positive value ONLY ! "  ) ;     
       else if ( ! ( (a <= b+c) && ( b <= a+c ) && ( c <= a+b ) ) )
            System.out.println ( "Error !\n\nOne rib can not be bigger than the two others !  "  ) ;     
       else
        {
           float s = (a+b+c) / 2 ;
           double area = Math.sqrt( s * ( s-a ) * ( s-b ) * ( s-c ) ) ;
           float perimeter = s*2 ;
           System.out.println ( "Perimeter of the triangle is: "+perimeter+"\n\nArea of the triangle is: "+area) ;     
        }// end of else
        }//end of method main
  } //end of class Triangle
```

The problem is that I get on screen *area* value 0.0 for every legal values of the triangle's ribs.

Why is that ? I did everything seems to be Ok .. isn't it ?!

thnx

Comment: For input 2, 2, 2 i got `Perimeter of the triangle is: 6.0
Area of the triangle is: 1.7320508075688772`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `s` variable is calculated in integer space default, you need to make one of the operands float to avoid rounding errors, e.g:

```
float s = (a+b+c) / (float) 2;
```

---

You might also consider constructing **easier** to read if-clauses, e.g.,

```
   if ( ! ( ( a >= 1 ) && ( b>=1 ) && ( c>=1 ) ) )
```

into

```
   if ( a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 )
```

If you're looking to create a [Equilateral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquilateralTriangle.html) triangle the second if clause can be converted from:

```
   else if ( ! ( (a <= b+c) && ( b <= a+c ) && ( c <= a+b ) ) )
```

into

```
   else if (a != b || b != c)
```

Comment: Didn't help...  1,2,3 gives: area 0.0

Comment: As soo many others have stated, the program *does* work. Make sure you are running the latest source code and not soem cached copy. Also, are you running oracle/sun java version?

Comment: You should write `2.0f` instead!

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
float s = (a+b+c) / 2 ;
```

to

```
float s = (float)(a+b+c) / 2 ;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing integer arithmetic.  You need to use `nextFloat()` or `nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems working... May it be the IDE that you're using?

```
macbook:java cem$ vi Triangle.java
macbook:java cem$ javac Triangle.java 
macbook:java cem$ java Triangle
Please enter first rib value : 
3
Please enter second rib value : 
4
Please enter third rib value : 
5
Perimeter of the triangle is: 12.0

Area of the triangle is: 6.0
```

Comment: macbook:java cem$ java Triangle
Please enter first rib value : 
1
Please enter second rib value : 
2
Please enter third rib value : 
3
Perimeter of the triangle is: 6.0

Area of the triangle is: 0.0

Comment: A triangle with sides 1, 2, and 3 *would* have an area of zero.

Comment: We're just stating the fact that your code works, but you need to work on number arithmetic which Johan Sjöberg's answer points to.. And btw, you cannot have a 1,2,3 triangle.... it is against the triangle rule

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my `Windows Vista` with `SUN JDK 1.6_b18` and `eclipse 3.6 RCP`

```
Please enter first rib value : 
5
Please enter second rib value : 
4
Please enter third rib value : 
3
Perimeter of the triangle is: 12.0

Area of the triangle is: 6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
float s = (a+b+c) / 2;
```

to:

```
float s = (float)(a+b+c) / (float)2;
```

The former is doing integer division which may be causing you some roundoff errors.

Comment: You should write `2.0f` instead!